# On the fly encryption for unencrypted cloud services?

Tags: file-encryption, cloud-computing

Today Amazon announced their Cloud Drive with unlimited storage for only 60$/yr. Microsoft did the same with Office 365 a while ago. I don't really want to entrust either service with my dearest documents in an unencrypted way.

So now I'd like to use one of these services with some workaround that...

- allows me to use these services to store my documents encrypted on their servers (
- is convenient, i.e. fast enough and without jumping through too many hoops
- works from shells on Linux and OSX and ideally also from the OSX GUI (at least for R/W access)

My first thought is something like a fuse system that mounts the cloud service as a local drive and that encrypts all files with my gpg key (e.g. a bit like [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157026-encrypted-fuse-filesystem/) combine with [onedrive-fuse-fs](https://github.com/mk-fg/onedrive-fuse-fs)).

Answer (score 2):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=+On+the+fly+encryption+for+unencrypted+cloud+services%3F ;-)

If you use such a service, you lose all of their web based services. So they effectively become purely a storage layer. Not a terrible idea, but removes much of the value from platforms like Dropbox with their countless integrations and so on.

There are many such services, with varying featuresets. Mobile supports tends to be patchy, but look at BoxCryptor, SafeMonk and my friends from Plug n Play, CrossCloud.

No need to use something like Fuse, you can use something like encfs if you really want to, but it'll be a pain to decrypt on mobile. There are also some tools that copy one directory to another, and sync the changes, encrypting from one to the other. So you have the encrypted directory in your cloud storage provider, and the unecrypted one on disk.

Personally, I'm using mega.co.nz because they handle encryption client side, have mobile apps, and include 50GB for free.